# Select2 - how to set placeholder when callback has no value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I want to set initial value in my `select2`, However if there is no initial value I want to set placeholder instead of value. Here is my code:

**Javascript :**

```
$(".neighborhood").select2({
    language: "en",
    placeholder: "Find your region ...",
    allowClear: true,
    data: $scope.regions,
    initSelection: function(element, callback) {
        var userNeighborhood = $cookies.get("neighborhoodInfo");
        if (!isUndefinedOrNull(userNeighborhood)) {
            console.log('user neighborhood is not null or undefined');
            userNeighborhood = userNeighborhood.split(',');
            var initialVal = {
                'text': userNeighborhood[0],
                'id': userNeighborhood[1],
            };
            callback(initialVal);
        } else {
            console.log('user neighborhood is null or undefined ');
        }
    }
});
var isUndefinedOrNull = function(val) {
   return angular.isUndefined(val) || val === null
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<select class="neighborhood js-states form-control" >
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Whenever *userNeighborhood* is not null or undefined , input of *select2* is replace by property value . Actually it doesn't set placeholder when *userNeighborhood* is undefined.

How to resolve it?

Comment: before asking a new question you maybe going to response on your question before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40328631/angularjs-select2-how-to-set-initial-value Whats up with it? You did not set "RIGHT ANSWER" on all questions you asked. whats up with you?

Answer (score 0):

`<select class="neighborhood js-states form-control" data-placeholder="Your Placeholder" >`

```
$('.neighborhood').select2({
minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
placeholder: function(){
    $(this).data('placeholder');
}
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: i appreciate your feedback.

Comment: @GhostDeveloper There will be none.